# It’s a shame you have to go now

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you explain the "shame" meaning in this context? Is it something bad, or like sorry, or sad?

> It’s a **shame** you have to go now. It would be nice if you had more time.

TIA

Comment: The speaker is expressing regret.  He is sad that the other is leaving.  You could substitute pity for shame and retain the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some definitions of the noun form of ["shame"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shame) from the Collins dictionary:

> 1. **Shame** is an uncomfortable feeling that you get when you have done something wrong or embarrassing, or when someone close to you has. ❌ (This does not fit your context.)
> 2. If someone brings **shame on** you, they make other people lose their respect for you.❌
> 3. If you say that something is **a shame**, you are expressing your regret about it and indicating that you wish it had happened differently.✅

Basically, you are saying that you are sad (or disappointed) that your friend has to leave so quickly. It is the third definition that you want.

When you are unable to understand the meaning of a word (one which has a few different meanings), you should look it up in different dictionaries. You should also look at the different usage examples to understand how the word is used in different situations.